# Refresh data on action button in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application which reads data from a folder once in a day using a `reactiveFileReader()`

```
df <- reactiveFileReader(
        intervalMillis = 24*60*60*1000,
        session = session,
        filePath = 'data/df.Rds',
        readFunc = readRDS
    )
```

This is then displayed as a table on the UI

```
output$demands_table <- renderDT({

  datatable(df(), rownames = FALSE)

})
```

The user additionally also wants a refresh button that he can click on to refresh the data manually, rather than being read in once per day through the `reactiveFileReader()`. This is where I am struggling. I have created an action button which does this:

```
observeEvent(input$refresh, {
  source('get_data.R') #script to update df.Rds
  df <- reactive(readRDS('data/df.Rds'))
})
```

This doesn't auto refresh the datatable on the UI. If I refresh my browser, then the data updates. I also tried creating `reactiveValues()`, but the results are the same.

```
rvs <- reactiveValues()

output$demands_table <- renderDT({
      rvs$df <- df()
      datatable(rvs$df, rownames = FALSE)

    })

observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      source('get_data.R') #script to update df.Rds
      rvs$df <- readRDS('data/df.Rds')
    })
```

How can I achieve this functionality of refreshing data through a `reactiveFileReader()` as well as by manually refreshing it through an action button?

Comment: Does changing the arrow as such work? `df <<- reactive(readRDS('data/df.Rds'))`

Comment: @Bas I tried changing the scope as you suggested, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Bas what seems to work is adding `makeReactiveVariable('df')` in my server code. Considering that `df` was already a reactive, I don't quite understand why this works though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Just based on your snippets, I don't know what's going on either. If you share a small reproducible example, I could take a look at it.

Comment: @Bas reprex for shiny has always been my waterloo! Will try and figure out how to make one. Thanks for your help!